# Dropdown: Breaking out of parent overflow property

Tags: css

I got a dropdown like this:

[image]

which is fine, until you reach the parents boundaries, at which point the dropdown gets hidden below the fold of the parent element.

[image]

I'm sure there is some very simple CSS to fix this, and have the dropdown "break out" of the parent container, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: LOL @ “sure there is an easy fix”. No, likely there is not. (Saying likely, because you failed to show any actual code to begin with, so we can not be sure what _exactly_ the situation is.) You will probably either need to implement a complex solution like https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/, or you need to place your dropdown elements else where in the DOM, and then format them to appear in the right place.

Comment: @CBroe yikes was fearing something like that. Oh well it's a minor thing, low on the priority list. Was just hoping for a quick fix that I didn't know about (am more of a backend guy, my CSS is basic at best).

Answer (score 0):

put on whole dropdown component

```css
overflow: visible;
```